# TypeError, trying to parse a Token value but impossible

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a token in a HTML page to create an autologin on Hackthebox login page but the script return me an error, i don't now why.
To login into this page i need the "_token" value ...

The login page that i try to parse :

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                <form id="loginForm" role="form" method="POST" action="https://www.hackthebox.eu/login">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="yIfppPolJsSoJbKhbI0mtB487kT8qXgsqlbFAxXw">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label class="control-label" for="email">E-Mail</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" required="" value="" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"> </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                        <div id="passwordArea">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="" required="" value="" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I tried to improve attrs but nothing to do, got the same error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import system, getcwd
from getpass import getpass
import requests
import json
try:
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
except:
        system("pip install bs4")
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://www.hackthebox.eu/login')
cookie = session.cookies.get_dict()
html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
token = html.body.find('input', attrs={'type':'hidden'})['value']
```

The result of this script is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gg.py", line 18, in <module>
    token = html.body.find('input', attrs={'name':'_token','type':'hidden'})['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server returns error page when it didn't find User-Agent header. Setting `headers=` parameter in `get()` method with `User-Agent` specified is enough:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://www.hackthebox.eu/login', headers=headers)
html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
token = html.body.find('input', attrs={'type':'hidden'})['value']
print(token)
```

This prints your token:

```
g1E39m2kn4sViJkoshbQQcZPS4HpWpf8Pxxme6jA
```